# Cytoscape.js connect two parent nodes to a child node

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there a way in Cytoscape.js to connect two parent nodes to a child node like the example in the picture?

[image]

Sorry if the question is something very basic but I couldn't find it in the documentation (maybe I have missed it).

All I could do was to create an edge between one parent and the child and another edge between the other parent and the child, which looks kind of messy and won't help me in the visualization of a family tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use segments edges to draw edges made of multiple straight lines: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/segments-edges